# Why is suggested not to use symlink for sites/all and sites/default?

Tags: 7

The status report for Pantheon (Drupal 7) says that sites/all sites/default and sites/default/settings.php is not a symbolic link, and it is considered as best practice. Why?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

You'd have to ask Pantheon to be 100% sure (they even did the initial development of [the module](https://www.drupal.org/project/site_audit)). However, the warning message in response to a situation where sites/all *is* a symbolic link, is:

> Avoid changing Drupal's site structure; remove the symbolic link and recreate sites/default.

So I think it's safe to assume this is just warning you not to mess with the structure of a Drupal site, which would probably cause problems or unexpected results when updated in future.

Comment: Yes, given the warning message, it seems the suggestion is not deleting the directories created when installing Drupal.